# boxplot without whiskers and out points

Tags: r, graphics, boxplot

Anyone knows how to eliminate the max and min bar in a R boxplot?
I tried the command above but it did not work.

```
boxplot(rnorm(0:200), main="abundances", xlab="Samples", ylab="Phylum abundance (%)", header=TRUE, cex=1, ylim=c(-5,4.), notch=F)
```

[image]

Thank you

I have this:
But want this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the `staplewex` and `whisklty` parameter to the baseplot like this:

```
boxplot(rnorm(0:200), main="abundances", xlab="Samples", ylab="Phylum abundance (%)", header=TRUE, cex=1, ylim=c(-5,4.), notch=F, 
        staplewex = 0,       # remove horizontal whisker lines
        outline = F,         # remove outlying points
        whisklty = 0,        # remove vertical whisker lines
        staplecol = "white", # just to be totally sure :)
        whiskcol = "white"   # dito
        )
```

[image]